# Why are Auth0 "Client Secrets" not one-way hashed (with salt)?

Tags: passwords, auth0, secret-key

When using the Auth0 Management API I was surprised that the client_secret is included when requesting `/api/v2/clients/{id}`: [API doc](https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2/#!/Clients/get_clients_by_id).

I would have expected that such information wasn't requestable, and that it would be hashed. Because it isn't it seems there is something I'm not understanding about API password security. Maybe it is conceptually different when you only can rotate the secret? Because then you don't run the risk of password reuse with a randomly generated string. Or is the reason something else?

Answer (score 1):

Secrets are assigned by Auth0 by default. As a result, it is necessary for a tenant admin to have access to the secret via the dashboard or management API.

With that being said, the management API is a powerful tool and access should only be granted to trusted clients. In addition, scopes should be as narrow as possible for those clients. Granting the read/update:clients scope should be done with prejudice.